# iphone - autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking

Tags: iphone

I have this line in my main code:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(animateMe) withObject:nil];
```

and this is the animateMe

```
- (void) animateMe {

  [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
     animations:^{
           [myView setAlpha:0.0f];

  }];

}
```

these are the messages I see on terminal

```
 *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1af740 of class myClass autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
 *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1af740 of class myClass autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
 *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1af740 of class myClass autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
 *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x193190 of class CABasicAnimation autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
 *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1b8230 of class NSConcreteValue autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
 *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1af740 of class myClass autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
 *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1c0ee0 of class CABasicAnimation autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
 *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1b4260 of class NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
 *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1aeb30 of class __NSCFDictionary autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
 *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1debd0 of class myClass autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
 *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1debd0 of class myClass autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
 *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1debd0 of class myClass autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
 *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1dad90 of class CABasicAnimation autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
 *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x16db40 of class NSConcreteValue autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
 *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1debd0 of class myClass autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
 *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1aafc0 of class CABasicAnimation autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
 *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1dfc10 of class NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
 *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1d1470 of class __NSCFDictionary autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
```

How do I solve that?

thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
- (void) animateMe {
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
     animations:^{
           [myView setAlpha:0.0f];

  }];
  [pool drain];
}
```

Comment: BTW there are many of these on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313122/nsautoreleasenopool-object-0x753c2f0-of-class-general-autoreleased-with-no-p

Answer (score 6):

It's telling you exactly what's wrong - you don't have an autorelease pool in place when that selector gets executed.  You need to add:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
```

at the beginning, and:

```
[pool drain];
```

At the end of your method.

Answer (score 1):

It may help someone

**@autoreleasepool** {

```
//enter code here
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`animateMe` is executing in a new thread since it is called from `performSelectorInBackground`. Every time when you spawn a thread, that thread should create and drain its own auto release pool.

From Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000047-CJBFBEDI) :
"... if you detach a thread, you need to create your own autorelease pool block."